# Error with clCreateBuffer but not with clEnqueueWriteBuffer

Tags: memory-management, opencl

I'm trying to write a large array to GPU device memory.

I first tried to perform this with

```
cl_mem obj = clCreateBuffer(context,
                            CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,
                            sizeof(int)*hugeVal,
                            &arr,
                            &error);
```

However, I would get a `CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY` error.  When I query my GPU, I see that

```
CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE ~= 0.5 GB
```

and that

```
CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE ~= 2 GB
```

The array that I'm trying to pass in is around `0.75 GB`.  I then instead started to use

```
cl_mem obj = clCreateBuffer(context,
                            CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                            sizeof(int)*hugeVal,
                            nullptr,
                            &error);    

clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commandqueue, 
                     obj, 
                     CL_TRUE, 
                     0, 
                     sizeof(int)*hugeVal, 
                     &arr, 
                     0, 
                     nullptr, 
                     nullptr);
```

This works as expected.  My understanding was that the second approach was identical to the first.  However, this doesn't appear to be the case.  Can anyone explain what's happening here?